# Android change in view depending upon a thread is over

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I have created a Thread in `onCreate()`. It is running fine. Now I want to change  something in view, when the thread is over. But if add it in the `run()` method, it is giving `android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` error. How to solve this problem?

```
Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
  ................
  ................
   //this line is giving problem
loader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                               
 }
};
updateThread.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html instead of Thread, and do your loader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) inside onPostExecute()

Answer (score 1):

In Android, only the original UI-Thread can make changes to it's View. That's security policy. A solution that might be interesting for you, too is shown in [this older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991178/android-handling-ui-from-other-thread).

Also have a look at Android's [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)-class (which is used in the Thread above).

But (as mentioned by zerpage), an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) might be the better way.

Comment: I used thread with halder combination. Its working fine. Thank yyou.